# Access SQL subquery - count records prior to each date in result set?

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I have a dump of Remedy tickets that includes the date submitted and the date resolved. What I need to do is calculate for every date that has at least one ticket submitted:

1. The number of tickets submitted on $date
2. The number of tickets resolved on $date
3. The number of tickets **still open** at the start of business on $date

I've got a query that gets me items 1 and 2, but I'm stuck on 3. I basically need a way to look at $date from the subqueries for 1 and 2 and use that as my WHERE clause for the subquery for 3.

This is the query that I have:

```
SELECT xDate, sTot, cTot, oTot FROM 
(
  (
    (
      SELECT xDate, COUNT(*) AS sTot
      FROM (
        SELECT FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS xDate FROM tblOpenINC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS xDate FROM tblClosedINC
      ) GROUP BY xDate
    ) AS sub

    INNER JOIN

    (
      SELECT FORMAT(LastResolvedDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS yDate, COUNT(*) AS cTot
      FROM tblClosedINC
      GROUP BY FORMAT(LastResolvedDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ) AS res

    ON res.yDate = sub.xDate
  )

  INNER JOIN

  (
    SELECT FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS zDate, COUNT(*) AS oTot
    FROM tblClosedINC
    WHERE FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") < DateValue(xDate)
    GROUP BY FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
  ) AS opn

  ON opn.zDate = sub.xDate

) 
ORDER BY DateValue(xDate) ASC
```

The last subquery doesn't work, since it doesn't know what xDate (the date from the first subquery) is.

If I have to do this with VBA I will, but I really would like to be able to do this all with SQL so that the raw data is easily available to dump into Excel and whatnot.

Also, for clarification: I have separate tables for tickets that were currently open or currently in a non-open state when I got the dump from Remedy, hence the UNION in the first subquery. Additionally, all of Remedy's date fields have a timestamp, so the FORMAT function strips out the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the sub query up to the top.  Maybe that will help.

```
SELECT xDate, sTot, cTot,  
(SELECT FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") FROM tblClosedINC WHERE FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") < DateValue(xDate) GROUP BY FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")) as zDate,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblClosedINC WHERE FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") < DateValue(xDate)GROUP BY FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")) as oTot
 FROM 
(
  (
    (
      SELECT xDate, COUNT(*) AS sTot
      FROM (
        SELECT FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS xDate FROM tblOpenINC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS xDate FROM tblClosedINC
      ) GROUP BY xDate
    ) AS sub

    INNER JOIN

    (
      SELECT FORMAT(LastResolvedDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") AS yDate, COUNT(*) AS cTot
      FROM tblClosedINC
      GROUP BY FORMAT(LastResolvedDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ) AS res

    ON res.yDate = sub.xDate
  )

) 
ORDER BY DateValue(xDate) ASC
```

Comment: Adding `AND FORMAT(SubmitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") = sub.xDate` to both of the subqueries should resolve that.  Unless there can be multiple zDates for one xDate.  If that is so, then it will not work.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. It's got to be counting from multiple dates - all dates prior to the given date.

Comment: Ok, I modified your query and it's getting me the numbers I want...it's just HORRENDOUSLY slow. I suppose this is just an unavoidable side effect of JET's crappy SQL engine. Thanks for your help though... I'll post the revised query momentarily on the OP.